# Programming Windows Embedded/CE OS 5.2 in vs2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-ce

I'm new at Windows CE programming. I need to develop a barcode scanner for Windows CE 5.2 OS. I reserched this topic and i realized that it is only possible in vs2005 or vs2008. But i read some articles about Xamarin and i needed to ask. Can i develop in vs2015 with Xamarin or some other frameworks?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually i didn't get how to do it. İ just found this (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14475/windows-ce-and-windows-mobile-6-5-support) forum. So i think i need to start it to develop in vs2008.

Comment: You can develop in VS2015 with Xamarin, but you cannot target Windows CE devices, I'm sorry, my last comment isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin does not support Windows CE and Windows CE development in VS2015 supports only Windows Embedded Compact 2013 (with some issues).
So you'll have to use VS2008 to develop CE 5 applications, both native or managed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand better now.